# I can not save from PhpStorm to WSL2

Tags: linux, windows, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 WSL) and I got a problem hopefully you can help me.

I can create a file from PhpStorm like `index.php` or anything, but I can not oversave an existing file. The message is

> Unable to save settings. Failed to save settings.Please restart PhpStorm.

I tried switch off Windows Firewall, but did not work.

I did reset a few times WSL and reinstall PhpStorm but did not work.

The Notepad++ can save files to the shared folder (`user/Jon/.azure`).

Comment: Try resetting PhpStorm settings (if you reinstall PhpStorm and did not select to delete the settings then they will be preserved). `File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...`

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. I am only using Windows 10 Home edition. Can be the problem?

Comment: In such case use `Help | Contact Support...` from PhpStorm and privately provide any requested information there.

Comment: Looks like it was a permission issue. Thanks your help.

Answer (score -1):

try to set to login in wsl as root from CMD terminal -> ubuntu20 config --default-user root